# PDFBox 2.0.7 unable to handle international characters

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.7 and having problems in getting string width of an internationalized string, below is the code snippet :

```
PDType1Font helveticaBold = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
String myString = "Crėamė";
float FONT_SIZE = 5.3f;
float titleWidth = 0.0f;
                                    
 titleWidth = helveticaBold.getStringWidth(mystring) / 1000 * FONT_SIZE;
```

It gives me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0117 ('edot') is not available in this font Helvetica-Bold encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

Please help.

Regards

Kris

Comment: See https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#i'm-getting-java.lang.illegalargumentexception%3A-...-is-not-available-in-this-font's-encoding%3A-winansiencoding   , and also update to 2.0.24 (unrelated).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr how to know whether the font is available in pdfbox, please help

Comment: Use a font file from your operating system and do the call as described in the link. In windows they are in c:/windows/fonts .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have solved this issue , here is the code, thanks @TilmanHausherr,

```
PDFont helveticaBold = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
String myString = "Crėamė";
float FONT_SIZE = 5.3f;
float titleWidth = 0.0f;

FontFileFinder fontFinder = new FontFileFinder();
List<URI> fontURIs = fontFinder.find();


for (URI uri : fontURIs) 
{
 File font = new File(uri);
 helveticaBold = PDType0Font.load(doc, font);
 try
 {
   titleWidth = helveticaBold.getStringWidth(myString);
   if(titleWidth > 0.0)
   {
       break;
   }
  }
  catch(Exception | Error e)
  {
          helveticaBold =PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
  }
}
if(titleWidth <=0.0)
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("Font Problem");
}
```

Regards

Kris

Comment: That is a bit weird; you're trying several fonts, and if one doesn't work, you catch the exception and try the next. So you have no real control what will appear in your document. It would be better to decide about specific (bold) fonts that look alike. The `EmbeddedMultipleFonts.java` example from the source code shows how to do this.

Comment: This is not a solution, also the param `doc` is not defined.